# How can i use a regular expression in PHP that matches a given group in the whole string instead of stops at first match

Tags: php, regex, query-string

I have the following expression:

```
[\?&]([\w-]+)=([\w=.|()+%-]+)
```

And i'm trying to validate the following querystring:

```
?tn_cid=280&tn_fk_specifications_planten_planttype=Groene%20kamer+planten|hangplanten|tuinplanten&tn_fk_ae-waterbehoefte=Weinig%20(2x%20per%20maand)&tn_fk_specifications_planten_plantheight=30%20-%2035%20cm&tn_fk_ae-hoogte-plant=Kleine%20planten%20(tot%2040%20cm)&tn_fk_ae-prijs=16.99-16.99
```

But my expression only matches the first part of the string and then stops:

```
?tn_cid=280
```

How can i get the expression to continue matching each group (i.e. ?key=value or &key=value) untill the end of the complete string?

Comment: Have yout thought about using parse_url (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: I am familiar with that function but i can't use it in this situation. The regex was needed as part of a validation rule in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the whole expression, and you can omit the capture groups to get a whole match:

```
(?:[?&][\w-]+=[\w=.|()+%-]+)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z0pmIj/1)

Or start with a `?` and optionally repeat the part with `&`

```
\?[\w-]+=[\w.|()+%-]+(?:&[\w-]+=[\w.|()+%-]+)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hj5viQ/1)

Comment: Cool thanks! This is a step closer what i'm looking for. One question though: if for example the last group does not match (e.g. &tn_fk_ae-prijs=16@99-16@99) , the regular expression will still match until that group.

What i want is to match the complete string so if one of the groups is invalid the complete expression should fail

Comment: @Tarik you can prepend and anchor ^ and append an anchor $ like `^\?[\w-]+=[\w.|()+%-]+(?:&[\w-]+=[\w.|()+%-]+)*$`